# How to get the duration of a video in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-data-api

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm trying to get the length (in seconds) of a YouTube video that is in an iframe for a purpose, can anyone help me?

This is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="youtube-video" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uSkPqgnBmUk?autoplay=1" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

I need it to be the easiest way in JS!!

Thanks in advance.

I tried to find it here on the website but without success.

**EDIT:**

I found a way but it doesn't seem to work...

```
$.getJSON( "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=uSkPqgnBmUk&part=contentDetails&key=AIzaSyCYc8h6t-T8QYf9WI9-Yk3tl_R8qeoOtAk", function( data3 ) {               
            
  var vidDuration = data3;
  var vidDuration2 = vidDuration.items[0][contentDetails][duration];
  alert(vidDuration2);
});
```

Comment: @Yogi See my edit.

Comment: @Sandro I posted an answer under that question. It should work.